# "X does not live long enough" error when overriding struct field (that has the same lifetime as other fields) inside nested scope

Tags: rust

I implemented a struct where I gave all reference fields the same lifetime. It seems like lifetimes don't work when I override field inside inner scope. I get an error:

> error[E0597]: `str2` does not live long enough

This is my code:

```
struct Test<'a> {
    a: Option<&'a String>,
    b: Option<&'a String>,
}

impl<'a> Test<'a> {
    pub fn new(a: Option<&'a String>) -> Self {
        Self {
            a,
            b: None,
        }
    }
}

fn main () {
    let str1 = String::from("test1");
    let mut test = Test::new(Some(&str1));
    {
        let str2 = String::from("test2");
        test.b = Some(&str2);
    }

    println!("{:?} and {:?}", test.a, test.b);
}
```

This is [minimal sandbox implementation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4c4ff512583bdea08c6e5966de257eba).

Could you explain how to force references to work with a defined lifetime? And why doesn't the code compile in this case?

Comment: I don't know rust that well, but it seems to me it is to be expected to get a compilation error here. You are trying to use a string after its memory has been freed. In languages without a/the borrow checker, this would be undefined behaviour or a runtime error.

Comment: How do you imagine this would work? `str2` is destroyed at the end of the block, so what would it print?

Comment: The compiler gives a pretty detailed explanation on exactly where the reference becomes invalid. A quick solution would be to remove the lifetimes and references, and allow your struct to take ownership of the strings.

Comment: @kmdreko same will work if I will use &str instead of String, so this is because I was disappointed

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo That's a different question :) I think you mean `"test1"` or `"test2"`, which is not `&str` but `&'static str`, meaning it is valid through the entire program.
If you would write `&'static String` in your struct, then that would work as well, but it's really hard to create a static `String`. But that discussion leads into the differences of `str` and `String`, which is I think what you should research.

Comment: So to summarize: You will find more information in `str vs String` and `static vs dynamic variables`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you misunderstand.

References with lifetime annotations don't *keep* values alive, they just specify how long they *must* be alive in order to be storable in the struct.

References do *not* take ownership of the variable. Lifetimes just ensure that whoever owns the variable does not destroy it before `'a` is over.

The compiler automatically figures out what `'a` must be. In your case, the latest point where `test.a` and `test.b` are getting used is the `println!(...)`. Therefore the compiler determines that `'a` of the `test` object must be a lifetime that is at least until the `println!(...)`.

Then, the compiler realizes that the owner of `test.b`, which is `str2`, gets dropped at the end of the `}`, which does not match the lifetime `'a` of the `test` object, as it doesn't reach the `println!(...)`.

If you look at the more detailed error message of cargo, by running either `cargo check`, `cargo build` or `cargo run`, you can see just that:

```
error[E0597]: `str2` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:17:23
   |
17 |         test.b = Some(&str2);
   |                       ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
18 |     }
   |     - `str2` dropped here while still borrowed
19 | 
20 |     println!("{:?} and {:?}", test.a, test.b);
   |                               ------ borrow later used here
```